# SSH.net - SSH connection works, but SCP returns "incorrect username and password"

Tags: c#, scp, ssh.net

Suppose I have a connection class with properties for SSHClient and SCPClient from `SSH.net` library (by Renci):

```
public class SecureConn
{
    public SshClient Ssh {get; set;}
    public ScpClient Scp {get; set;}

    public SecureConn(string host, string usr, string pwd)
    {
        this.Ssh = new SshClient(host, usr, pwd);
        this.Scp = new ScpClient(host, usr, pwd);
    }

    ...

}
```

When I try to run commands with SSH - everything works fine. However, when I try to use `this.Scp.Upload()` (notice same credentials in constructor) to upload a file from network share to Linux server I get System.IO.Exception returning "Incorrect username or password". What might be the cause of getting this error?

Do I need to install any software for SCP to work fine on Windows? Or is it the network share source that is somehow generating this message? Maybe Linux server needs to have set different password for SCP?

I checked with WinSCP and I can connect flawlessly with it and copy files around.

Note: Above is just a code sample, not actual code, but the workflow is basically the same. I am positive about that it's Renci's ScpClient.Upload method that throws the error, so I'm looking outside the code to find an error.

Comment: Faulty SCP client? Maybe try a different one? You can integrate with WinSCP from C#, they have a client lib on their website. (note that you must have winscp installed to use that). Also keep in mind there are different protocols for file transfer over SSH, you might be looking for a client that supports SFTP (not just SCP)

Comment: What do you mean by faulty SCP client? As far as I know SSH.net is one of the most recommended libraries for SSH/SCP in .NET. Also, I am not able to change this (I'm not the only user of this code).

Comment: It's hard to imagine how a server could give authentication failures for scp while permitting ssh. An scp connection is just an ssh connection where the client requests the server to run scp after authentication. During authentication, the server doesn't even know the client will be doing scp. You say the code that you included isn't actual code. You should reduce your code to a standalone program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Kenster Thing is I don't suppose the code is the issue here. I might be missing some dependencies and the sample I provided is used here to show that I'm using the same credentials for both SSH and SCP (this actually is the reduced code). The code works on other PCs I tested, yet I can't get it to work on mine, hence the question about other factors that might interfere with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the cause was not in SSH.net library, but in credentials used to log into network share. For anyone having same issue, storing the credentials by Windows (check "Remember my username and password" in login prompt) to network share fixed the issue. Having one-time access does not. Probably mapping a drive would work too, but I haven't checked that.